# WSLをシェルにしている場合のVSCodeタスク機能の挙動について

Tags: linux, node.js, vscode, wsl

VS Codeで統合シェルにWSLを使っているのですが、タスク機能でYarnスクリプトを実行しようとすると

> Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.

というエラーを吐きます。
統合シェルでYarnを叩くと正常に実行できます。

タスク機能でenvを実行し環境変数を見るとnodeのパスが追加されておらず、nodeが実行できないためエラーが起こっていると思われます。

wslの.bashrcで下記のように確かにパスは通しているので、

```
export N_PREFIX="$HOME/n"; [[ :$PATH: == ":$N_PREFIX/bin:" ]] || PATH+=":$N_PREFIX/bin" # Added by n-install (see http://git.io/n-install-repo).
```

おそらく、VS Codeのタスク機能はwslのシェルで設定した環境変数を読んでいないものと思われます。

コマンド前に以下のように書けばコマンドを実行できるのですが、

```
"export PATH = \" $ HOME / n / bin：$ PATH \" &&"
```

すべてのコマンド前にこれを追加するのは効率的でなく、また美しくないので、よりスマートな解決策はないでしょうか？

---

### 追記

統合シェルは

> "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"

に設定して使っています。wsl.exeの方はVS Codeが非インタラクティブシェルを走らせるとき、bashではなくshになるっぽい？

Windowsのバージョンはwindows 10 Proの1809(October 2018 Update)です。

情報足らずで申し訳ないです。

Comment: 統合シェルにWSLを設定するにあたってどう設定なさいましたか？　また、分かれば Windows 10 のバージョン情報があると嬉しいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。統合シェルはVS Codeの設定で"、terminal.integrated.shell.windows"を、"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" に設定して使っています。windowsは10Proの1809(October 2018 Update)です。